# generate unique key on each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, eslint

I have a highlight feature for the search term entered in the input. Below is the flow

1. Below is the highlight function which works perfect.

   ```
   const getHighlightedText = useCallback((text, highlight) => {
   // Split text on highlight term, include term itself into parts, ignore case
   const parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi'))
   return (
     <span>
       {parts.map((part, i) => (
         <span
           key={i}
           className={
             part.toLowerCase() === highlight.toLowerCase() ? 'text-black' : ''
           }
         >
           {part}
         </span>
       ))}
     </span>
   )},[])
   ```
2. Below is my map function where I am looping the data when search result found

   ```
   {item?.map((data) => (
       <li key={data.title}>
          {getHighlightedText(
              data.title,
              searchTerm,
              data?.action?.categoryId
          )}
       </li>
    ))}
   ```

Problem 1

If I use `key={i}` in my highlight function to map over selected items, then ESlint is throwing below error

`Error: Do not use Array index in keys  react/no-array-index-key`

Problem 2

If I remove array index from key and use id in my function `useCallback((text, highlight, id) => {` and pass it to key then browser will give error because each selected alphabet will have the id which will create duplicate keys running on each render.

`Encountered two children with the same key,` 78`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.`

Not sure what could be the solution for this, if somehow I can create unique ID for each item on each render.

Comment: If the list is static and won't alter then using an `id` is fine, but if they change then consider adding a key say some unique value from server ...

Comment: I'm gonna make a confession... I use `Math.random()` as React keys if there are no other options... Maybe you can too!

Comment: @KcH you should always have a way for React to identify and recoginize which components are the same between rerenders. Because if the parent rerenders and React has no way of identifiying which child components are the same it will just do an initial render on all children (which will also scrap any states you might have had in the children) - so ALWAYS have a unique key that won't change on rerender of the parent

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I guess I conveyed the same , `id` I meant is the `index` when mapped over an array ....

Comment: @caTS I feel index is better than Math.random() just removing that extra work (if the list never changes) 

Comment: @caTS that's not "fixing" the error/warning you get. It's just masking it. If the key of components won't stay the same between rerenders of the parents (which with math.random() they won't) React can't recognize which components stay the same (so basically the whole point of the key gets's defeated) - so Math.random() masks the Error but does not fix it

Comment: The issue gets resolved if I use `Math.random()`

`<span
            key={Math.random()}
            className={
              part.toLowerCase() === highlight.toLowerCase() ? 'text-black' : ''
            }
          >
            {part}
          </span>`

Comment: For your first problem just don't use index directly but add some uniqueness to the keys with string interpolation `key={'my_specific_list_${i}'}`

Comment: @H.Husain, you maybe know, but Math.random() does not guarantee 100% unique id. Of course, it's a very rare case, when you could see the same "thing" in Math.random() output, but you should consider this fact if you want an ideal environment without any errors. If you really want this, either change your eslint configs to only "warn" (instead of "error") for `react/no-array-index-key` rule or return from your server something `100% guaranteed unique` value as @KcH pointed out.

Comment: What you have done in your code is fine. Disable the warning for this line.